# If you don't clone in Java then what do you do and what do you call it?

Tags: java, oop

Does anyone have any suggested or established best practices and naming conventions for copy constructors / factory methods etc in Java?  In particular, say I have a class `Thing` and I want a method somewhere that returns a new `Thing` with the same value as a `Thing` passed in (or as the instance if it's an instance method).  Would you have this as constructor or a static factory method or instance method?  What would you call it?

As per the title, I want to avoid `clone()` and `Cloneable`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid clone() and Cloneable?

Comment: @Thomas Owens, see here: http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html

Comment: to the answers that state copy constructor as the solution: copy constructor does not properly handle all cases. For instance when you don't know the concrete class (but you can still use the copy constructor inside your clone/copy/whateveryoucallit method).

Answer (score 16):

Effective Java recommends either of the following:

1. A copy constructor (as noted by others):

   public Item(Item item)
2. A copy factory method:

   public static Item newInstance(Item item)

(Also, no copying for immutables)

The primary difference is that with #1 you choose the actual class of the result, and with #2 the implementer can return a subclass.  The semantics of the class may guide you into which one is best.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a copy method or a copy constructor (as the case may be). If it was a static method, then I would call it a factory.

In terms of what to do, the most flexible and long living option is a copy constructor. This gives subclasses the ability to copy themselves just like the parent.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a constructor

```
...
public Thing(Thing copyFrom)
{
    attr1 = copyFrom.attr1;
    attr2 = copyFrom.attr2;
    //etc...
}
```

then when you want to clone it

```
Thing copy = new Thing(copy from me);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the [clone()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())-method, if you want. Another used practice is a constructor, that takes an object of this type, i.e. [new ArrayList(anotherList)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options, implement `Cloneable`, add a copy constructor but my preferred way is to use a method (static or instance) that has a name which is descriptive of what the copy operation is doing - is it a deep or shallow copy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [immutable data structures](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29). The only reason you feel that you need `clone()` is that you're mutating your objects in place. Stop doing that. Think about how you can:

- Make your classes final.
- Make fields in your classes final and private.

For example, here's a "setter" for an immutable 3D vector object:

```
public Vector3D setX(double x) {
  return new Vector3D(x, this.y, this.z);
}
```

So I guess what I'm saying is... I use copy constructors instead of mutation, and I just name them according to the attribute that I want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to implement the copying method in the *source* object, e.g.:

```
interface Has3DCoords {
    void setLocation(double x, double y, double z);

    void copyCoordsTo(Has3DCoords dest);
}
```

You would then implement copying with a piece of code like:

```
class Thing implements Has3DCoords {
    private Point3D loc;
    // ...

    void setLocation(double x, double y, double z) {
        loc.setLocation(x, y, z);
        // or: loc = new Point3D(x, y, z);
    }

    void copyCoordsTo(Has3DCoords dest) {
        loc.copyCoordsTo(dest);
        // or: dest.setLocation(loc.getX(), loc.getY(), loc.getZ());
    }

    OtherThing createOtherThing() {
        OtherThing result = new OtherThing();
        this.copyCoordsTo(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This can be useful if:

- It does not make sense to clone the whole object
- There is a group of related properties that are often copied as one unit
- You do not want to expose `loc` as a property of `Thing`
- The number of properties is large (or there are many such groups) so a constructor that required all of them as parameters would be unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the nicest approach to copying objects but the following is sometimes useful if you wish to perform a **deep copy** of a *Serializable* object. This avoids having to write copy constuctors, implement Cloneable or writing factory classes.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

//Serializes the input object
oos.writeObject(input);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

//Copy of the input object
Object output = ois.readObject();
```

Don't forget to handle the exceptions and to close the streams nicely.