# Clone() vs Copy constructor- which is recommended in java

Tags: java, clone, copy-constructor

clone method vs copy constructor in java. which one is correct solution. where to use each case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method

Comment: Avoid `clone` *at all costs* and go for your own copy solution.

Comment: Copy constructors are better than Object.clone() because they
Don’t force us to implement any interface or throw any exception but we can surely do it if it is required, 
Don’t require any casts, 
Don’t require us to depend on an unknown object creation mechanism, 
Don’t require parent class to follow any contract or implement anything, 
Allow us modify final fields, 
Allow us to have complete control over object creation, we can write our initialization logic in it. Read more https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2017/01/Java-cloning-copy-constructor-versus-Object-clone-or-cloning.html

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Clone is broken, so dont use it.

> THE CLONE METHOD of the Object class
>   is a somewhat magical method that does
>   what no pure Java method could ever
>   do: It produces an identical copy of
>   its object. It has been present in the
>   primordial Object superclass since the
>   Beta-release days of the Java
>   compiler*; and it, like all ancient
>   magic, requires the appropriate
>   incantation to prevent the spell from
>   unexpectedly backfiring

Prefer a method that copies the object

```
Foo copyFoo (Foo foo){
  Foo f = new Foo();
  //for all properties in FOo
  f.set(foo.get());
  return f;
}
```

Read more
http://adtmag.com/articles/2000/01/18/effective-javaeffective-cloning.aspx

Comment: Um, clone isn't broken. Why do you think it is? If it is because it doesn't work if you don't override it - well, that's its contract.

Comment: @Bozho, read _Effective Java 2nd Edition_, Bloch explained it quite well. Doug Lea doesn't even use `clone()` anymore except to clone arrays (http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Comment: I don't really understand why cloning cannot be simpler. Is this a choice ? or there are really harsh problems behind that in the general case ?

Comment: Not sure about that `copyFoo` code.

Comment: @polygenelubricants `clone()` and `Cloneable` are wrong from design perspective. It's not that they don't work per se. And all shallow copies may behave randomly. That's why I suggested the deep copy mechanism.

Comment: @Bozho: that's like saying that a square wheel is only wrong from design perspective only. You can install it on a car and the car will still move. "It's not that they don't work per se."

Comment: @polygenelubricants I'm not using `clone()` either, that's why I suggested beanutils. But my point is that `clone()` _can_ be used, though _"judiciously"_. In simple cases it works pretty well. So let's ammend the car metaphor - it's like saying that Russian cars work. Well, they do, but not quite well.

Comment: I freely admit that I haven't (yet) read Effective Java but I will say that Cloneable has the advantage of being an interface. That is to say that you can limit the parameters of generic classes and functions to only accept classes that implement Cloneable, then simply call clone(). Without it, I don't believe there is a (good) way to enforce that and you would likely resort to reflection to discover a class's copy constructor. That also makes the assumption that if Foo has a constructor that accepts a Foo, that **is** in fact a copy constructor. At least you know what clone() should return.

Comment: So, `clone()` is indeed a bad idea, but, instead of this sort-of-standardized method for copying the object, you just suggested ad-hoc reimplementing the very same thing??? Don't you think hat's even worse than `clone()` itself?

Comment: @Bozho Stupid analogy. I don't know any Russian car that doesn't work well. Have you ever seen one?

Comment: @spaaarky21 if i got it correctly, if a class implements the `Clonable` interface it not necessarily has a `clone` method nor is it guaranteed that the `clone` method will do the right thing, it is rather a convention. You could have a similar convention for classes having a copy constructor, eg implementing an `CopyConstructible` interface that has no methods but merely indicates that the class has a copy constructor

Answer (score 58):

Have in mind that `clone()` doesn't work out of the box. You will have to implement `Cloneable` and override the `clone()` method making in `public`.

There are a few alternatives, which are preferable (since the `clone()` method has lots of design issues, as stated in other answers), and the copy-constructor would require manual work:

- [`BeanUtils.cloneBean(original)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) creates a shallow clone, like the one created by `Object.clone()`. (this class is from [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/))
- [`SerializationUtils.clone(original)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html) creates a deep clone. (i.e. the whole properties graph is cloned, not only the first level) (from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)), but all classes must implement `Serializable`
- [Java Deep Cloning Library](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/) offers deep cloning without the need to implement `Serializable`

Comment: How does that deep cloning library work on any object? I smell code that is probably riddled with reflection

Comment: yes, a lot of reflection :)

Comment: which of these does not copy references and copy by values? BeanUtils.cloneBean(bean) is copying references, but im using an android version (android-java-air-bridge.jar) not original apache version.

Comment: i have tried java deep cloning library and works great!! it does not copy references :D, copy values

Answer (score 34):

clone() was designed with several mistakes (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092540/accessing-clone-from-java-lang-object)), so it's best to avoid it.

From [Effective Java 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 11: Override clone judiciously

> Given all of the problems associated with Cloneable, it’s safe to say
>   that other interfaces should not extend it, and that classes
>   designed for inheritance (Item 17) should not implement it. Because of
>   its many shortcomings, some expert programmers simply choose never to
>   override the clone method and never to invoke it except, perhaps, to
>   copy arrays. If you design a class for inheritance, be aware that if
>   you choose not to provide a well-behaved protected clone method, it
>   will be impossible for subclasses to implement Cloneable.

This book also describes the many advantages copy constructors have over Cloneable/clone.

- They don't rely on a risk-prone extralinguistic object creation mechanism
- They don't demand unenforceable adherence to thinly documented conventions
- They don't conflict with the proper use of final fields
- They don't throw unnecessary checked exceptions
- They don't require casts.

All standard collections have copy constructors. Use them.

```
List<Double> original = // some list
List<Double> copy = new ArrayList<Double>(original);
```

Comment: You are copying `original` as an `ArrayList` when it may have been another type of list (e.g. `LinkedList`). This is exactly why clone is better than a copy constructor.

Answer (score 19):

Keep in mind that the copy constructor limits the class type to that of the copy constructor. Consider the example:

```
// Need to clone person, which is type Person
Person clone = new Person(person);
```

This doesn't work if `person` could be a subclass of `Person` (or if `Person` is an interface). This is the whole point of clone, is that it can can clone the proper type dynamically at runtime (assuming clone is properly implemented).

```
Person clone = (Person)person.clone();
```

or

```
Person clone = (Person)SomeCloneUtil.clone(person); // See Bozho's answer
```

Now `person` can be any type of `Person` assuming that `clone` is properly implemented.

Comment: It's unfortunate that someone once suggested that a proper implementation of clone should involve `new` rather than `super.clone()`, since the proper behavior for `clone` is to call `super.clone()` if that method itself calls `super.clone()` (or is the built-in memberwise clone for object); if `super.clone()` ends up calling `new`, the only not-totally-broken behavior for `clone()` is to call `new` itself, but then every child class must override `clone()` to do likewise whether or not the child class would otherwise need to override `clone()`.

Comment: The "deep vs shallow" question doesn't seem ambiguous to me in most cases.  A `SomeCollection<T>` exists to hold the *identities* of things of type `T`, and calling `clone()` on one should yield a new instance of the same type which is detached from the original but holds references to the same `T`'s.  Nothing that can be done to the original or the clone should affect the *identities* of the objects stored in the other.  I really don't understand what the confusion is.

Answer (score 3):

See also: [How to properly override clone method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326758/how-to-properly-override-clone-method/2326801#2326801). Cloning is broken in Java, it's *so hard* to get it right, and even when it does it *doesn't really offer much*, so it's not really worth the hassle.

Comment: It's much easier to get right when you have a `final` class that inherits from `java.lang.Object`. It's tricky when the class contains mutable data structures (and thus requiring a deepcopy), but the same challenge would also present itself in a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Great sadness:  neither Cloneable/clone nor a constructor are great solutions:  I DON'T WANT TO KNOW THE IMPLEMENTING CLASS!!!  (e.g. - I have a Map, which I want copied, using the same hidden MumbleMap implementation) I just want to make a copy, if doing so is supported.  But, alas, Cloneable doesn't have the clone method on it, so there is nothing to which you can safely type-cast on which to invoke clone().

Whatever the best "copy object" library out there is, Oracle should make it a standard component of the next Java release (unless it already is, hidden somewhere).

Of course, if more of the library (e.g. - Collections) were immutable, this "copy" task would just go away.  But then we would start designing Java programs with things like "class invariants" rather than the verdammt "bean" pattern (make a broken object and mutate until good [enough]).

Comment: There is *some* hope for this sort of thing, at least for value objects that you make in your project:  https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html

Comment: If copying was easy, it already would have been part of Java. But it isn't. Do you want a shallow copy, a deep copy, or somewhere in between? Do you have different behaviors for different classes depending on what you're copying and what you're casting to? What happens with Generics? What happens when what you're copying is a parameter for a Generic? This might be a bit easier to reason about without inheritance and without mutability, but those are baked into the heart of Java (the language). Maybe a language like Scala that makes guarantees about mutability will make cloneability easier.

Comment: @IceArdor - I want a shallow copy, with type inference about the result based on the source, and the same implementing class used internally.  At least, if the source implementation has a default constructor, I guess.

Comment: @Roboprog Are you sure that shallow copy didn't work when you wrote your comment years ago? Shallow copies almost never make sense to me. newMap = new HashMap<>(oldMap) works when I really just need shallow copy.