# Cloning objects of inner classes

Tags: java

I have written a class A such as following

```
class A <E> {  // class A has objects of E

    int x;

    private B<T> next // a object of inner class

    class B<T> { 
        // an inner class having objects of type T

        T[] elements = (T[]) Object[x];
        // has other stuff including many objects  
    }

 public A<E> func ( B<E> val ){
  Here I want to clone the value of val so that I can do different operations on other   
 }
```

The problem comes that I wish to write `B<E> Temp = B<E>Value.clone()` where Value is defined in the code.

but it says that clone is not visible.

What should I do to make it so....

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Can you provide a code sample which includes your `clone()` routine? You might also want to implement the `Cloneable` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example to the answers from Peter (not tested, may need some syntax checks):

```
class A <E> {  // class A has objects of E

    int x;

    private B<T> next // a object of inner class

    class B<T> implements Cloneable {
        public B<T> clone() {
           try {
              B<T> klon = (B<T>) super.clone();
              // TODO: maybe clone the array too?
              return klon;
           }
           catch(CloneNotSupportedException) {
              // should not occur
              throw new Error("programmer is stupid");
           }
        }
        // an inner class having objects of type T

        T[] elements = (T[]) Object[x];
        // has other stuff including many objects  
    }

 public A<E> func ( B<E> val ){
     B<E> clone = val.clone();
     // more code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

clone() is protected so you just need to redefine in B to do whatever you need.

Comment: What do you mean by redefine ??? Could you give an example ?? as in I need to implement Cloneable in the nested class or what ??

Comment: Just overwrite it and increase its visibility: make it public. Inside, you will call super.clone() and then -- if needed -- you'll make a deep copy.

Comment: again could you give an example ... I wrote super.clone() in the inner class and eclipse does'nt let me run this. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

It's better to not use `clone()` but to implement a copy constructor on `B`:

```
 class B extends A { 
    // an inner class having objects of type 
    List<String> strings = ArrayList<String>();

    public B(B that) {
       super(that); // call the superclass's copy constructor
       this.strings = new ArrayList<String>();
       this.strings.add(that.strings);
    }

    // ...
}
```

then call

```
public C func ( B val ){
   B clone = new B(val);
}
```

(removed the generics stuff to limit demonstration on the copy constructor itself)

Comment: clone is broken, there are a lot of questions and answers on this topic (Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java)

Comment: On "It's better to not use clone()", what if you're cloning a `B` type but are not sure of its runtime type (because it could be a subclass of `B`)?

Comment: @Steve Kuo - I don't understand that comment. A `B` is a `B` at runtime, a subclass of `B` is not a `B`. Subclassing was not part of the question, but anyway, I edited the question. Copy Constructor is compatible with inheritance. (and `clone` is still broken and we should simply avoid it).

Comment: How is a subclass of `B` not a `B` (it will pass instanceof)? Are you saying `LinkedHashMap` is not a `HashMap`?

Comment: @Steve - A `LinkedHashMap` is a `LinkedHashMap` and it extends `HashMap`. You *create* it by calling the `LinkedHashMap` constructor. Calling `getClass()` on an instance of `LinkedHashMap` returns `"java.util.LinkedHashMap"`. *is-a* is ambigious in this case, I was not talking about inheritance, I was talking about the type of an instance.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Your copy constructor answer is incomplete and incorrect if B can have subclasses - which it can, as its non-final. `public C func ( B val ){ B clone = new B(val); }` This code will always create a B instance, even if the val passed is actually a subclass of B. This is where clone is needed, but I agree it's tricky to use and somewhat broken in places.

Comment: @Zebsy - subclasses is a different story - if you want to clone some `E extends B`, then call the copy constructor of `E`. If you use `new B(B source)` with an `E` instance, you'll *not* create a clone of `E`, but that was never the intention.