# Accessing clone() from java.lang.Object

Tags: java, oop, clone, access-modifiers

Here is something that I cannot understand.

In `java.lang.Object` the `clone()` is defined with `protected` modifier. By definition than it can be accessed by name inside its own class definition, by name inside any class derived from it, and by name in the definition of any class in the same package.

Here the `Sample` class is in another package, and obviously it can't access `clone()` from the `Object` class. But as `Sample` derives implicitly from `Object`, why is it not able to access it? The definition doesn't say that it HAS to satisfy both conditions (inside same package AND also to be a subclass).

```
public class Sample {

  public Object foo() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
   ... 
   return someObject.clone();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In your case, the `clone()` method is not visible because you are not calling it from a subclass. `Sample` derives from `Object`, so it can access its own `clone()` method, but not that of other objects.

Object `clone()` was designed with several mistakes. So it is not a good practice to use it - it is very hard to get it right:

- the assumption is that not every object is clonable by default
- if you override `clone()` making it public, it will still fail, because each class has to implement `Cloneable`
- `Cloneable`, however, does not define any methods, so the users of the objects can't refer to it as `Cloneable` and expect a clone method.
- every class in a hierarchy must call `super.clone()` for the default cloning mechanism to work

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance/2156367#2156367) for alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me: http://ideone.com/eST8Y

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public Object foo() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return this.clone();
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        new Main().foo();
    }
}
```

**This compiles without error.** It still throws a runtime `CloneNotSupportedException` because `Main` does not implement [`Cloneable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

> A class implements the `Cloneable` interface to indicate to the `Object.clone()` method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.
>
> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the `Cloneable` interface results in the exception `CloneNotSupportedException` being thrown.

---

[@Bozho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092540/accessing-clone-from-java-lang-object/5092600#5092600) is really the right answer here, though. **Just don't use `Object.clone()`.**

See [*Effective Java*, Item 10: Override `clone` judiciously](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&lpg=PP1&ots=UZQ-9niM1_&dq=joshua%20bloch&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Item 11 in later editions).

Answer (score 0):

The class type of `someObject` is important here. Object `someObject` might not be overriding the `clone()` method of `Object` class, thus making is invisible to class `Sample`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "not able to access it"? Do you mean it won't compile or do you mean it throws the CloneNotSupportedException.

`Object.clone()` will throw `CloneNotSupportedException` if your class doesn't implement the Cloneable interface.