# array copy by value fails (with clone() or arraycopy()) (Android, Java)

Tags: android, clone, arrays

In order to make a copy of an array that holds a copy of the values instead of by reference I do the following:

```
int[][][] copy = {{{0}},{{0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}},{{0}},{{0,0}}};
System.arraycopy(spelerSpel, 0, copy, 0, spelerSpel.length);
```

then change a value IN THE COPY:

```
copy[SPELER_NUMMER][0][0] = baanSpelerNummer;
```

which results at that moment in the ORIGINAL (spelerSpel) array holding the same changed value, e.g.:

```
{{{4}},{{0}},{{0,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}},{{0}},{{0,0}}};
```

as the copy. I also tried .clone(), same result. What am I doing wrong?

By the way I target Android API 8, which doe not support Arrays.copyOf().

Comment: I'm not sure, but from the documentation it doesn't sound like arraycopy is recursive-  it would copy the outermost array, but not recursively copy inner arrays of a multidimensional array.  You may need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy()` does not support deep copies, but it does pretty well in terms of performance for simple arrays.

You can use it with some additional loops to create your own multi-dimensional `arraycopy3d()`:

```
public int[][][] arraycopy3d(int[][][] array) {

     int[][][] copy = new int[array.length][][];

     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         copy[i] = new int[array[i].length][];
         for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
             copy[i][j] = new int[array[i][j].length];
             System.arraycopy(array[i][j], 0, copy[i][j], 0, array[i][j].length);
        }
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Well actually the resulting (multidimensional) copy is (correctly) produced by arraycopy (as well as by clone(). The problem however is that it turns out to be a copy by reference instead of by value as I expected.

Comment: Could a copy constructor ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java/)) help and how in this case?