# What is good practice? A copy constructor or a defensive copy method

Tags: java, copy-constructor, defensive-programming

I have a class Graph and I need a copy of that graph. I am going to modify the internals of graph object ( eg: delete an edge etc. ). I have 2 ways to implement a graph.

1. A copy constructor
2. A method called 'getGraph() { return new Graph(this)}'. This method getGraph can do a defensive copy.

The only advantage of copy constructor, from my understanding is copy-at-will. This means if I dont want to modify graph object, there is not need for 'getGraph' to do a defensive copy.

Now coming back to my question.

1. Is it better to use a copy constructor or is it better to use a function which returns copy of self object ?
2. Why ?

Comment: Why do you have `getGraph` method in `Graph` class? Are you having a reference to a `Graph` instance in the `Graph` class itself?

Comment: yes. its kind of return this.

Comment: What is a copy constructor and what is a defensive copy? I think you need deep copy.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper. Now that sounds strange. Can you show your current code? And elaborate more onto why you actually need this?

Comment: I understand i need a deep copy, but is it via a copy-constructor or via an explicit method that does a deep copy ??

Comment: @JavaDeveloper. The best way to make a deep copy is via serialization. A copy constructor is good. But if your objects contains reference to some mutable object, which in turn again contains a mutable object, you would need to make deep copy of all of them. Serialization will take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what you need this for, it's preferable to define copying as a method because a potential subclass can override a method. If `Graph` had a subclass that for example adds color to each node, calling a copy constructor in `Graph` you could only copy the plain graph, losing the additional information and functionality in subclasses. A method that copies the graph on the other hand could be overridden in the subclass.

You may find the [`Object.clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method helpful, but keeping in mind its requirements (have to implement [`Cloneble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and override the `clone` method) and limitations (only makes a shallow copy) you might as well write your copy method from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand your question

In copy constructor you would do something like

```
Graph copy = new Graph(objectToBeCloned);
```

and in getGraph() you would do

```
Graph copy = objectToBeCloned.getGraph();
```

I suggest make your Graph class implement `Cloneable` interface and override `clone()`  method to get a deep copy you need.

Comment: Thanks for help, but my question is which of the following options is a better one ?

Comment: Performance wise I think none. It's merely a design choice. I suggested above answer because the functionality is already provided all you need is to implement it according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a copy constructor have more semantics over a getGraph method inside a Graph object. So between the two I would prefer a copy constructor.

Please don't consider using clone, it is broken by design, read [Object Identity](http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/ObjectIdentity.html) for more information about it.
You have also some alternatives, that are expressed here : [clone vs copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are still looking for the answer to this question but because the question is not marked as answered, I am going to answer it.

Since you had chosen to go with the copy constructor

```
Graph clonedGraph = new Graph(originalGraph);
```

or defensive copy

```
Graph clonedGraph = originalGraph.getGraph();
```

I can tell that you are aware of the disadvantages of `Object.clone()`, And I will suggest you go with defensive copy strategy because it is polymorphic and also give you the advantage of inversion control or dependency injection.

Copy constructor strategy will fail if you have a child class of `Graph` (Which you might need in future) and try to assign the object of that child class to the reference of `Graph` and then try to create copy for it. You can read more on [Java Cloning - Why Copy Constructors Are Not Sufficient](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2017/01/java-cloning-why-copy-constructors-are-not-sufficient-or-good.html)