# Java adding functionality to an existing class with a new class while still exposing all methods of previous class

Tags: java, class, this, subclass, extends

I want to do something like a `super()` but without passing anything to the constructor.

Something like copying all the variables in their current states, which were set to methods inside that class.

I want to avoid doing stuff like `getPlayer()` in a wrapper class when the wrapper class is the Player just with extra methods.

I don't want to move these extra methods into the Player class because it's not part of the Player class it's something a Player class may become into but not at all times.


I still want to be able to run constructor of the SpecialPlayer with it's own variables it has to set while still maintaining it as a Player from whatever instance I pass into it.

The `Player` class variables may change at any time while it's casted into a `SpecialPlayer` class and the `SpecialPlayer` class should have up to date variables same as `Player` at all times.. Yes it has to the same reference exactly at all times by the looks of it.

Here is some pseudo code I wrote to try to illustrate the problem

```
public class Player {
    private int money;
    private boolean bar;

    public Player(int money) {
        this.money = money;
        bar = true;
    }

    public void toggleBar() {
        bar != bar;
    }
}

public class SpecialPlayer extends Player {
    private Player player;
    private long foo;

    public SpecialPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player; //wrapper way not good...
    //this = player; ??? doesn't compile...
    foo = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() { //<-- this is stupid.
        return player;
    }
}
```

```
Player player = new Player(12345);
player.toggleBar(); //it's now false, also it's not a constructor variable.

SpecialPlayer specialPlayer = new SpecialPlayer(player);
specialPlayer.getFoo(); //some long number value.
specialPlayer.toggleBar(); //now it should be true!.
player.toggleBar(); //should be false.
specialPlayer.toggleBar(); //should be true.
```

Comment: you are extending `Player` class and also creating object of player class in your `SpecialPlayer`! why?

Comment: You're confusing the 'has a' and 'is a' relationships.  Why would you want SpecialPlayer to both extend Player and to contain a Player member?  What purpose does that serve?

Comment: I suspect you may fundamentally misunderstand inheritance.  When you create a `SpecialPlayer` instance, the new instance **is** a `Player`, as well as a `SpecialPlayer`.  Therefore, you probably don't need to include a `Player` argument in the `SpecialPlayer` constructor, unless it really does refer to a *different* `Player` (e.g. an opponent or a teammate or something).  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: I don't know how to make a `SpecialPlayer` behave like a `Player`, Okay I know the `extends` keyword should make the `SpecialPlayer` a `Player` but how do I pass my instance of a Player into the `SpecialPlayer` I can't use the `Player`'s constructor because it's already constructed before hand using `new Player(1234);`

Comment: I still want to be able to run constructor of the `SpecialPlayer` with it's own variables it has to set while still maintaining it as a `Player` from whatever instance I pass into it.

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is turn one Player in to a subtype at run time and that's just not how it works. If you want a SpecialPlayer you need to create an entirely new object. Maybe you need a copy constructor.

Comment: I want to create a new object of SpecialPlayer each time but I want it to represent a old existing Player but the variables inside SpecialPlayer must all be cleared everytime it's constructed.

Comment: @Radiodef At least in C++, the "copy constructor" does exactly the opposite case: it is possible to construct a `Player` by copying from a `SpecialPlayer`, but not the other way around (like what OP meant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you want to do.

```
public SpecialPlayer(Player player) {
    super(player.money);
    bar=player.bar;
    foo = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

A new `specialPlayer` will have the money and bar of the player passed to it.

Alternatively, if you want to set every field to the same as the `Player` passed you could try this:

```
public SpecialPlayer(Player player) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    super(player.money); //Still need to do this
    for(Field sfield:player.getClass().getDeclaredFields();){
        sfield.setAccessible(true);
        sfield.set(this, sfield.get(player));
    }
}
```

This will set all of the fields of the new `SpecialPlayer` which are declared in `Player` to the value of that field in the `player` passed.

To be able to change the state of the original `Player` and have it reflected in the new `SpecialPlayer` as your update requires you could change all of your references to the original `Player` to point to the new `SpecialPlayer`.

```
Player player= new Player(123);
SpecialPlayer special = new SpecialPlayer(player);
player=special;
```

Another thing to think about, do you really want to make a new `SpecialPlayer` with all the same fields as an old `Player`, or do you actually just want to make the old `Player` special? It might be easier to make the `SpecialPlayer` constructor this:

```
public SpecialPlayer(int money){
    super(money);
}
```

Then for all your players who might later become special you would create like this:

```
Player player1 = new SpecialPlayer(123);
Player player2 = new SpecialPlayer(345);
```

And then just cast them to `SpecialPlayer` when you want them to be special.

```
SpecialPlayer special = (SpecialPlayer)player1;
```

This way you don't need to change your references or create new objects when you make your player special.

You could also add a method in `SpecialPlayer` which does what the constructor currently does and call it whenever you want to make that player special:

```
public void setSpecial(){
    foo = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

.

```
SpecialPlayer special = (SpecialPlayer)player1;
special.setSpecial();
```

You may also need a flag which could be toggled when a player is `setSpecial()` to distinguish  if they should use an overridden method or revert to the super method.

Comment: I tried the `super()` idea before posting this question it doesn't work because there are some variables that are not initialized by Player Constructor but they still have changed while the Player class was in use.

Comment: I think I need something like public `public Player(Player player) { this = player; }` I wonder.

Comment: That is what the line `bar=player.bar` is for. bar will be set to whatever the player's bar is when it is passed.

Comment: @SSpoke *"there are some variables that are not initialized by Player Constructor but they still have changed while the Player class was in use"* - So create a separate constructor for cloning a player; see my answer for details.

Comment: @Alex: That code will not compile, `bar` is private.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that, sorry. You could change the access if you want this to work then.

Comment: Yeah but `bar` was just a example, I Also don't want to update all the variables everytime I add a new variable into the Player class with SpecialPlayer seems there is no clone command?.. even that sounds bad.. why copy it twice if it already exists?

Comment: Blah I now think I should just keep making the Player class bigger and bigger (even if it's rarely used) instead of trying to split everything into smaller objects.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're a little confused about how inheritance works

for example, this slightly changed version of your code below

```
class Player {
    private int     money;
    private boolean bar;

    public Player() {} // I've added this guy, so your subclass is not forced to implement a similar constructor as Player(int money)

    public Player(int money) {
        this.money = money;
        bar = true;
    }

    public void setBar() {
    }
}

class SpecialPlayer extends Player {
    private long    foo;

    public long getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

with this structure, it's legal for example to do things like

```
SpecialPlayer sp = new SpecialPlayer();
sp.getFoo(); //method specific to special player
sp.setBar(); //method inherited from Player
```

there's no sense on wrapping a Player inside SpecialPlayer, if you want SpecialPlayer to be a Player.

UPDATE: how to assign the data from an existent Player into a SpecialPlayer

Think on a class like a memory space. For example

```
Object SpecialPlayer

[X] money
[X] bar
[X] foo

Object Player

[X] money
[X] bar
[ ] foo
```

So it's easy to see that you can do something like

```
Player p = new SpecialPlayer()
```

because p must know only the data from "money" and "bar" and, despite "foo" is still there, from p point of view, it's irrelevant, because all p knows is "money" and "bar"

the opposite, sure, is not true, because

```
SpecialPlayer sp = p
```

will force the interpreter to resolve the problem of assigning the field "foo" for p. There are two situations here

1. p is actually a SpecialPlayer, so you can just typecast it like sp = (SpecialPlayer)p. The interpreter will just realize that p was initially created as a SpecialPlayer and then, there's a "foo" somewhere.
2. p is not a SpecialPlayer, but a pure Player. In this case, there's no way for the interpreter to guess what value "foo" must have. In java, there's no way to just let SpecialPlayer be initialized with the same fields it has from Player and assume for example that "foo" is null. In this case, you have to manually do this assignment, creating a method such as

   ```
   public void valueOf(Player p){
       this.money = p.money;
       this.bar = p.bar;           
   }
   ```

Of course, this could be a static method that returns a SpecialPlayer, or the constructor as you've planned. But the problem is the same. How to assign "foo" to SpecialPlayer. The java interpreter simply "prefer" not to assume it as null (or any other default value) and let the developer implement it.

UPDATE #2 - there's a good question here

why can't (or shouldn't) I assign a superclass into a subclass, so I can just copy the attributes that I need and assuming the remaining ones are null?

for example

```
 Player p = new Player()
 p.setMoney(1)
 p.setBar(bar)

 SpecialPlayer sp = p
```

meaning

```
 sp.setMoney(1)
 sp.setBar(bar)
 sb.setFoo(null)
```

?

well, in java, when you assign an object into another, you're not actually copying the values from one into another. You're just creating a link. That's why you can assign

```
 SpecialPlayer sp = new SpecialPlayer()
 //set SpecialPlayer attributes
 Player p = sp
 SpecialPlayer sp2 = (SpecialPlayer)p;
```

without losing any information.

If we were copying the values instead, the code above would just erase the value of "foo" in the last line, because Player had no place to put "foo"

Is that good? Maybe. Imagine what would happen if, assigning one object into another, we were performing something like a "deep copy" of all the value attributes.

Imagine typical persistent entities, that are many times complex graphs of objects, sometimes very deep, sometimes with cycles. You would have a lot of memory problems with that.

Comment: How do I do like  `SpecialPlayer sp = existingPlayer` while also resetting all variables inside `SpecialPlayer` (calling it's constructor)

Comment: Okay I'll wait for your answer, sounds promising.

Comment: So no way to make the `SpecialPlayer` instance be same as `Player` just with some extra variables? I already updated question I want the `SpecialPlayer` to change everytime `Player` variables change too so reference must match. Also not every `Player` can be a `SpecialPlayer` only one `SpecialPlayer` at any given time. That's why I don't want to put it into Player class. If I put it into the class that contains all Players like new variable `Player specialPlayer;`.. then I have no problem.. but all those variables I must list in that Player Container and those variables really clog it up space

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to, at runtime, add functionality to an existing class, then you should be looking into dynamic proxies and/or aspect oriented programming (AOP).

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html for information about creating Proxy objects that implement a given interface but can pass-through calls as desired.

Alternatively, you need to re-evaluate your class model.  Specifically, if a Player can become a SpecialPlayer *sometimes*, then SpecialPlayer doesn't really have an 'is-a' relationship with Player.  More likely Player has a 'has-a' relationship with some functionality that might or might not be available.  For instance, if you *become* a SpecialPlayer by picking up some sort of powerup, then that should be expressed by some kind of attribute or inventory functionality on Player that might return null.  Unfortunately your example is too abstract to give you any concrete advice on the best course of action in refactoring.

Also, `setBar()` should be called `toggleBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Okay I know the extends keyword should make the SpecialPlayer a Player but how do I pass my instance of a Player into the SpecialPlayer I can't use the Player's constructor because it's already constructed before hand using new Player(1234);

You can't extend an existing instance of a `Player` to make it a `SpecialPlayer`, it just doesn't work like that.

You *can* however make a clone of a `Player` that's a `SpecialPlayer`

```
class Player
{
    public Player(Player other)
    {
        //Copy all instance variables from other into this here
    }
    //Other constructors/instance variables/etc here
}

class SpecialPlayer extends Player
{
    public SpecialPlayer(Player other)
    {
        super(other);
        //Set SpecialPlayer-specific instance variables here
    }
}

//Example of how to create a SpecialPlayer clone of a Player:
Player myPlayer = new Player();
SpecialPlayer specialPlayer = new SpecialPlayer(myPlayer);
```

Comment: Is there any way to copy all variables with a command instead of pasting every variable?

Comment: @SSpoke: There is [`.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29), but it's [typically not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883) because its meaning is not precisely defined, and usually only does a shallow-clone.  The only other option to is set every field manually.

Comment: Thought about this some more.. I can't do this because the `SpecialPlayer` should always be the same reference as `Player` what if the `Player` gets some changes while it's also a `SpecialPlayer` will `SpecialPlayer` variables also reflect the new changes? If not then this solution will not work.

Comment: You can assign a `SpecialPlayer` reference to a `Player` variable, nothing special needs to be done.  As I said, however, you cannot change an arbitrary `Player` into a `SpecialPlayer` if it wasn't originally created as one, so what you're looking to do is impossible.  If you want the `SpecialPlayer` to update when the original `Player` reference does, you'll need to set up callbacks in the setter-methods, which I'm sure is way too complex for whatever it is you're actually trying to accomplish.