# Cannot instanciate correctly new object clone with copy constructor

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a clone of an object using copy-contructor, unfortunately seems that all the modification to the clone are reflected to the original object.

I have this interface

```
public interface Car{
     public Car newInstance(Car c);
}
```

and various Object hat implements the interface in this way

```
public FerrariSpyder implements Car{
    String name;
    String description
    ArrayList<Feature> featureList;

    public FerrariSpyder(String name, String description, ArrayList<Feature> featureList){
      this.name=name;
      this.descripion=descripion;
      this.featureList=featureList;
    }

    @Override
    public Car newInstance(Car c) {
        return FerrariSpyder.newInstance((FerrariSpyder) c);
    }

    public static FerrariSpyder newInstance(FerrariSpyder fs) {
        return new FerrariSpyder(fs.getName(), fs.getDescription(), fs.getFeatureList());
    }

}
```

Now assuming that I have a `Car` object named `originalCar` I try to clone this with

```
Car clone=originalCar.newIstance(originalCar);
```

If I add elements in `featureList` of the clone also the `featureList` in `originalCar` will be modified.

Comment: can you post the snippet that is giving you issue (and also a little description of what the error is)?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new instance of your object, but the fields are shared.

Concerning `name` and `description`, there is no problem, because Java treat `String`s as immutable. If you try to "modify" them, you will in fact change the reference to them.

Concerning `featureList`, that's another story. You currently have the same list instance in both objects. You need to create a new instance of the list when you call the constructor of your new object, like this:

```
public static FerrariSpyder newInstance(FerrariSpyder fs) {
    return new FerrariSpyder(fs.getName(), fs.getDescription(), new ArrayList<>(fs.getFeatureList()));
}
```

**Note:** Be careful, there are now 2 lists, but they share the same objects. This means 2 things:

- If you modify a `Feature` in one of the lists, **you'll see modifications** of that `Feature` in the other list.
- If you add/remove an object from one list, the other list will **not be affected**.

If you want to be able to modify the `Feature` objects in the lists without affecting the other list, you'll have to do deep copies of these objects as well.

---

**Side note:** What you are doing here is basically writing a `clone()` method, which you named `newInstance()`. You should probably implement the `Cloneable` interface to do it the Java way ;-)

Comment: and deep copies of the features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll go to try your suggestion. I'm try this because I have heard that native clone mehod is riskful in this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java 

I would be happy to know your opinion about this

Comment: @AndreaF Very interesting discussion. I would personally stick with `clone()` because of hierarchy reasons raised in that post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5026085/1540818

Comment: @AndreaF On the other hand, on has to be careful. If you want to use clone, you have to implement it properly in every class of the class hierarchy up to Object.