# Is there a risk in new clazz(this) from Clazz.clone?

Tags: java, clone

After a build break, one developer complained it was because the previously available `Clazz.clone()` (not the real name of the class :)) has been removed, so his call to `clz.clone()` is breaking.

Upon which the author of `Clazz` advised that the client code be changed to use `new Clazz(clz)`. \

Is there risk in implementing the `clone` method to return `new Clazz(this)`? What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is risk in doing that, but it's unnecessary.  Have your one developer change his function call.

```
// this is the same
var myClazz = thatClazz.clone();

// as this
var myClazz = new Clazz(thatClazz);
```

The new method uses something called a Copy Constructor which in my opinion looks cleaner than using .clone().

Further, a discussion should be had with your development team about modifying code that other modules are dependent on.  Any methods or properties that are not private should have references checked before a change.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg it is Java if `Clazz` is subtype of `var`, no?

Comment: This is true, but I think it still tackles elements of the problem.

Comment: the benefit of clone() is that it is polymorphic, copy constructor is not!

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that clone is a method and a constructor is a constructor.

This means that

```
Clazz x = ...; 
Object xClone = x.clone()
```

returns whatever method clone of x.getClass() returns: a Clazz object or an object *of a subclass of Clazz*. Compare this to

```
Clazz x = ...;
Object xCopy = new Clazz( x );
```

which will give you a *Clazz object*, even when x references a SubClazz extends Clazz.

Presumably this doesn't matter to "the author of Clazz".

Comment: There are many instances when `new Clazz(x)` should /not/ return a subclass but rather fail loudly. Slicing is not always good.

Comment: Now I see that you did not. Since I was asking specifically for risks in using clone I perhaps misinterpreted your description of difference between a method call and a constructor call to imply some benefit/loss analysis

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of discussion around clone vs copy constructor on the internet, eg [Clone() vs Copy constructor- which is recommended in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java)

Adding a clone method will work but given that this is all internal code, why introduce the extra complexity?

It does sound like you could do with a process to handle breaking changes. May be just do something simple such as mark clone as deprecated for a while to give developers a chance to stop using it.

I've seen people waste hours trying to maintain backward compatibility on internal apis and more hours arguing about trivial changes like this.