# Persist Object's value after copying in Java

Tags: java, object

My sample code -

```
private final DataObj dataObj = getDataObjs();

private final DataObj dataObj1 = new DataObjImpl();
dataObj1 = dataObj; //I need the value of dataObj1 to be the same even if the value of dataObj is modified anywhere further down in a class.
```

My problem is that if the value of the Object `dataObj` is being modified then the value of the second Object `dataObj1` is also modified but I need the second Object `dataObj1` to be immutable (Value should persist), is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone() (or) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance

Comment: You ought to be implementing your own constructor that properly copies a `DataObj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the assignment statement, `dataObj1 = dataObj;`, `dataObj1` refers to the *exact* same object as `dataObj`. The solution is to assign a copy of the object referenced by `dataObj`. One way to do this is via a copy constructor, something like:

```
dataObj1 = new DataObjImpl(dataObj);
```

Below is an example:

```
class DataObjImpl {

   private Object data;

   public Object getData() {
      return data;
   }

   public void setData(Object data) {
      this.data = data;
   }

   // copy constructor
   public DataObjImpl(DataObjImpl obj) {
      this.data = obj.data;
   }        
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example in the form of a code snippet with respect to my sample code? so should I substitute this line instead of direct assignment "dataObj1 = dataObj.clone();"?

Comment: @user3652212 I edited my answer. A copy constructor is preferrable to a `clone()`. See http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12.'

Answer (score 1):

You need to deep copy the object. Or at least use the `clone` method to copy it over.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java.