# Java: Is setters should make `Clone` or it's up to caller pass `new` copy?

Tags: java, coding-style, clone, getter-setter, cloneable

What considered to be the best & common practice if I want to make sure that after setter is called the object cannot be modified from outside? In the code there is detailed simple self explained example, With 2 options dilemma.

```
//caller scope
CustomObject original = new CustomObject(params...);  //original state 1
MyClass mMyClass = new MyClass(original);
original.modifyMe(params...);  //original state 2
mMyClass.setCustomObject(original);
original.modifyMe(params...); //original state 3


/*!!!REQUIREMENT: mMyClass.CustomObject should be in state 2!!!*/


class MyClass {

    private CustomObject mObject;

    public MyClass() {
        this.mObject = new CustomObject();
    }

    public MyClass(CustomObject obj) {
        this.mObject = obj.Clone();
    }

    //mObject is private, modified only through setter
    public getCustomObject() {
        return this.mObject;
    }

    public setCustomObject(CustomObject obj) {
        //Option 1 in the caller  
        //mMyClass.setCustomObject(new CustomObject(params...));
        this.mObject = obj;

        //Option 2 in the caller
        //mMyClass.setCustomObject(callerCustomObject);
        this.mObject = obj.Clone();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to make sure that the object can't be modified outside of the class, you have to make copies *both in and out*. But don't use `clone` - the object should have a copy constructor.

Comment: @RealSkeptic 1. Why use copy in get? I don't know maybe from outside they want just to use not modify the object, I think it's better to make the check in the in direction. 2. What you mean copy constructor in java? this is not why we need Clone()?

Comment: If you `get` the object, then you can change it and it will change the object inside the class. So always copy both in and out. `clone()` is [broken](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2427946/4125191).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I implement the Clonebale interface and override the clone with copy constructor style - is this the best practice?

Comment: The best practice is not to implement `Cloneable` and not to override `clone`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic In the university course that's what we learned - in java use clone. What is the alternative?

Comment: @michael [Real Skeptic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666502/java-is-setters-should-make-clone-or-its-up-to-caller-pass-new-copy#comment53178827_32666502) is absolutely right. You need to make copies both in and out for immutability. You should never use `clone()`, it's a mistake in the Java API. Both of these points are covered in [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683); which is required reading for all Java developers.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understood the point with in & out copies. My question is regarding alternative to clone() in order to make a copy. What you are basically suggest is to make my custom copy method in the rule of copy constructor/what clone() intended to be?

Comment: @michael Bloch also covers recommended alternatives. A `static` method that creates an instance and copies properties across is often a good choice, but a copy constructor is more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use clone here. Rather than making inefficient defensive copies, try making CustomObject immutable. You can modify state by adding withXXX methods (roughly equivalent to setXXXX) but they create a new instance of the host object (rather than the Object being passed in). [Project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html) comes with some handy preprocessor annotations for creating Immutable objects with Withers. Also see the Immutables 2.0 project.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class CustomObject {

   @Wither @Getter
   private final int state;

}

CustomObject one = new CustomObject(1);
CustomObject two = one.withState(2);

assertThat(one.getState(),equalTo(1));
assertThat(two.getState(),equalTo(2));
```

By using genuine Immutable Objects you will incur much less memory (& GC) and CPU overhead than with defensive copies - as well as **much** simpler code.