# Returning objects from a public method

Tags: java

I have a method:

```
public List getDocuments(Long orgClientId, long userId) {

    // do stuff
    List list = new ArrayList();
    // do stuff to fill the list. The list will be of hashmaps.

    return list;
}
```

I don't want my list to be modified outside this method. How should I return it then? Cloning it? Or just returning a new instance like

```
return new ArrayList<>(list);
```

would do it?

Comment: [cloning shouldn´t be used in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java), so you are fine if you return a new `ArrayList`

Comment: Please don't use raw types: use `List<HashMap<?, ?>>`, probably with more specific type bounds on the key and value types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it superficially unmodifiable thus:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(list)
```

This wraps the list in order that invoking any of the mutation methods will result in an exception.

However, does it *really* matter to you if somebody modifies the list? You are giving back a new list instance each time this method is invoked, so there is no issue with two callers getting the same instance and having to deal with interactions between the mutations.

Whatever step you take to attempt to make it unmodifiable, I can just copy the list into a modifiable container myself.

It's also quite inconvenient to me as a caller if you give me back something which I can't detect whether it is mutable or not - it looks like a `List`; the only way to see if I can mutate it is by calling a mutation method. That's a runtime failure, which makes it a PITA.

---

Update, to add an alternative.

An alternative to `Collections.unmodifiableList` is something like Guava's `ImmutableList`: this will likely be faster than `Collections.unmodifiableList` since it does not simply provide an unmodifiable view of existing list by wrapping, but rather provides a custom implementation of `List` which forbids mutation (there is less indirection).

The advantage of this is that you can return `ImmutableList` rather than just the `List` returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList`: this allows you to give the caller a bit more type information that they can't mutate it. `ImmutableList` (and its siblings like `ImmutableSet`) mark the mutation methods `@Deprecated` so your IDE can warn you that you might be doing something iffy.

The caller *might* choose to disregard that information (they assign the result to a `List`, rather than an `ImmutableList`), but that's their choice.

Comment: suppose I call the method `getDocuments` and get the value of the list assigned to a new list called newList. Now if I modify the old list just by, say, `list.add()` this newList also changes - which I don't want. So, it does matter if someone modifies the list.
Also, by using unmodifiableList, I guess I will also have to add exception handlers at places, right?

Comment: That's not what the code in your question does, though, and it isn't what your question describes. If you have specific requirements, you need to state them, so that these can be taken into account in giving an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the object returned by umodifiableCollection can't directly be changed, but could change through other means (effectively by changing the internal collection directly).

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("One");
list.add("Two");
list.add("Three");
List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

   // this doesn't throw an exception since it's using the add
   // method of the original List reference, which is no problem
list.add("Four");
System.out.println(unmodifiableList);

  // this, however, throws an exception
unmodifiableList.add("Five");
```

> unmodifiableList returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.
>   This method allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to
>   internal lists. Query operations on the returned list "read through"
>   to the specified list, and attempts to modify the returned list,
>   whether direct or via its iterator, result in an
>   UnsupportedOperationException. The returned list will be serializable
>   if the specified list is serializable.