# Helper method to clone Date?

Tags: java

Sonar says that [mutable members should not be stored or returned directly](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S2384?layout=true)

> Mutable objects are those whose state can be changed. For instance, an array is mutable, but a String is not. Mutable class members should never be returned to a caller or accepted and stored directly. Doing so leaves you vulnerable to unexpected changes in your class state.
>
> Instead, a copy of the mutable object should be made, and that copy
>   should be stored or returned.
>
> This rule checks that arrays, collections and Dates are not stored or
>   returned directly.

I'm trying to store one date. To solve the sonar alert, I created two helper methods to return a copy of my original date.

Example A:

```
public static Date clone(Date originalDate) {
    if(date != null) {
        return new Date(originalDate.getTime());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Example B:

```
public static Date clone(Date originalDate) {
    if (date != null) {
        return  (Date)originalDate.clone();
    }
    return null;    
}
```

If I use the constructor way (example A),  I loose the possible extra information that contains my original date.

Should I copy my originalDate with the constructor (example A) or with clone (example B)?

Comment: It doesn't really matter which one you choose. I would write: `return originalDate != null ? new Date(originalDate.getTime()) : null;`

Comment: If you want to make it immutable, you could store `date.getTime()` as a `final long`. Then just rehydrate it to a `new Date(fieldName)` when you need it. If you want slightly stronger typing, create a trivial wrapper class for the long with `toDate()`/`fromDate()` methods.

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't mess with `java.util.Date`. If you have a chance to use JDK 8 I would propose you to use Instant, otherwise you could simply store epoch milliseconds or Joda Time.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I copy my originalDate with the constructor (example A) or with clone (example B)?

Choose the way that is more readable. i.e. example A.

However [Ternary Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) has got a use here.

And you might want to look here: [Clone() vs Copy constructor- which is recommended in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java)

Comment: Even if it is often assumed that Date is just a wrapper around a long value, that is actually not true. `new Date(oldDate.getTime())` is not just a simple 'copy constructor call', `getTime()` may require some calculations to return a result and the new object is not necessarily technically equal (though semantically) to the old Date object.