# Make a new instance of an unknown subclass using superclass object in java

Tags: java, abstract-class, clone, subclass, superclass

Here I have an abstract class Person and multiple subclasses:

```
public abstract class Person {

    public String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class ComputerScientist extends Person {

    public String job;

    public ComputerScientist(String name, String job) {
        super(name);
        this.job = job;
    }
}

public class SoftwareEngineer extends Person {

    public String job;

    public SoftwareEngineer(String name, String job) {
        super(name);
        this.job = null;
    }
}
```

This is what I run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    person.add(new ComputerScientist("ben", "job"));
    person.add(new SoftwareEngineer("larry", "job"));
    Random r = new Random();

    Person person = people.get(r.nextInt(people.size() - 1);
}
```

Person becomes the same as the Person in the list, how do I get it as a person clone. Cloning and new Instance do not work.

I can probably do it using a copy method (requres me to rewrite a great deal of code) but is there any (perhaps more efficient) way to do it without?

Comment: Create an `abstract clone()` method which your subclasses have to  implement. Then you can call `person.clone()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method to create a new Object of the Person(as per the sub class) and another method to copy the states in the new object. Refer below approach for the basic implementation of the same.

```
public abstract class Person{
  ...//your states and methods
  protected void copy(Person copiedPerson){
        copiedPerson.name = this.name;
  }

  public abstract Person getCopyPerson();
}

public class SoftwareEngineer extends Person{

     ....//your states and methods
    @override
     protected void copy( Person copiedPerson ){
          super(copiedPerson);
          copiedPerson.job = this.job;
     }

    @override
    public Person getCopyPerson(){
       Person copyPerson = new SoftwareEngineer();
       copy(copyPerson);
       return copyPerson;
    }

}
```

Now whenever you fetch the object of Person, simply call `getCopyPerson()` on it to get a copy object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of `clone()` - see also [Clone() vs Copy constructor- which is recommended in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java)

So, instead use a copy constructor or copy method, that accepts a person and then transfers the relevant information

Comment: Good answer. Also the (`Object`'s) `clone` method really is misleading as it only does a shallow copy. Which for example leaves `String` fields 'uncloned' which is more often than not unexpected and leads to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class cloneable with implements with Cloneable interface. and at object user .clone() method to clone of person class object

Comment: While you are (I assume) trying to get the correct idea through you should try rewording your answer as it's currently really not understandable.