# Need help entering an ArrayList into my WordSearchPuzzle program

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Hi I'm new to Java and I'm having difficulty with creating my word search puzzle program. I'm trying to get a user to enter an ArrayList of words so it can be entered into my puzzle but I keep get an error when I enter an Array of Strings can anybody help please??

```
 import java.io.* ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
public class WordSearchPuzzle
{
    private char[][] puzzle ;
    private ArrayList<String> puzzleWords ;
    private int letterCount = 0 ;
    private int gridDimensions;

    public WordSearchPuzzle(ArrayList<String> userSpecifiedWords)
    {
        this.puzzleWords = userSpecifiedWords ;

    }

    private void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size() ; i++){
            letterCount = puzzleWords.size() + letterCount ;
        }
        gridDimensions = letterCount * 2;
        puzzle = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions] ;
    }

    private void generateWordSearchPuzzle()
    {

    }

    public void fillPuzzle()
    {
        int i, j, r;
        for (i = 0; i < this.gridDimensions; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < this.gridDimensions; j++)
                if (puzzle[i][j] == ' ') {
                    r = (int) (Math.random() * letterCount);
                    puzzle[i][j] = letterCount.charAt(r);
        }
    }

    public void fill() 
    {
        int i, j, gridDimensions, r, c;
        boolean added;
        this.clear();
        for (i = 0; i < WordSearch.words.size(); i++) {
            ws = (WSWord) WordSearch.words.elementAt(i);
            row = (int) (Math.random() * this.rows);
            col = (int) (Math.random() * this.cols);
            added = false;
        }
```

Comment: Post your complete code and the error you receive when trying to execute it.

Comment: I have to input an array of words to be loaded into my Puzzle but i keep getting this error when I enter a String like {"hello","bye"}I get this error: Error: illegal initalizer for java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>

Comment: Please post the code that calls the `WordSearchPuzzle` constructor. My guess is that you are trying to pass a `String[]` instead of a list.

Comment: You really need to post your code, otherwise we're unable to see precisely what you're doing.  You cannot initialise arraylists with `{}` constructs - that is reserved explicitly for arrays.

Comment: Same homework http://stackoverflow.com/q/10192950/211197

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to puzzle as your array of Strings, it isn't, it's a two-dimensional array of char. Perhaps you need

```
private String puzzle[];
```

Unfortunately it's not very clear from the given code example what exactly are you having an issue with.

Comment: I have to input an array of words to be loaded into my Puzzle but i keep getting this error when I enter a String like {"hello","bye"}I get this error: Error: illegal initalizer for  java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>

Comment: No, you can't initialise ArrayList with an array. You can try something like: this.puzzleWords = java.util.Arrays.asList(yourStringArray);

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use the = to copy arraylist and its contents:
From a similar question: 
[clone(): ArrayList.clone() I thought does a shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592478/clone-arraylist-clone-i-thought-does-a-shallow-copy)

Adapted to your case:

```
this.puzzleWords = new ArrayList(userSpecifiedWords)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue here. He is allowed to do that but of  course changing userSpecifiedWords will cause a change in puzzleWords array as they point to the same array.

Comment: What i typed created a clone in a diferent memory position. What he posted above will not copy the contents of the Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize puzzleWords.

```
private ArrayList<String> puzzleWords = new ArrayList<String> ();
```