# Creating a copy of an ArrayList of HashMaps

Tags: java, arraylist

I have some code which creates an ArrayList of HashMaps, I then need a copy of that ArrayList of HashMaps for performing calculations, but I want the original to stay the same.

I have tried all sorts, from people's SO answers, here's my current code:

```
List<Map> counts = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `counts` list is filled with HashMaps.

I need a copy of that but I don't want the calculations I perform on the copy  to affect the original.

I have tried:

```
List<Map> copyCounts = new ArrayList<Map>(counts);
```

But whenever  I perform changes it alters the original

Comment: [Clone it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592478/clone-arraylist-clone-i-thought-does-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: Never use clone.  it's broken.

Comment: Don't think you can clone Maps anyway?

Comment: You can use java-8 stream for calculations, it will not change the state of the original list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to create a deep copy:

```
List<Map> counts = ...

List<Map> copy = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map m : counts){
  copy.add(new HashMap(m));
}
```

Comment: For future reference, use generics!

Comment: How would you use generics for this @JacobG.

Comment: @user3667111 I can't give an example without knowing the key/value types of the `Map`.

Comment: Both Doubles @JacobG.

Comment: @user3667111 Then it would be along the lines of replacing `Map` with `Map<Double, Double>`

Comment: @user3667111 A compilation error will be thrown if you attempt to add anything other than a `Double` to the `Map`, rather than an exception thrown at runtime.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm now refreshing my memory on java generics :) thanks for the pointers @JacobG.

Answer (score 1):

That's because all the maps you're adding to your new array list are still by reference. You also need to copy the individual maps as well.