# assigning same values to objects in java

Tags: java, object, clone

let's suppose there are two objects of class abc

`abc obj = new abc(10,20);` // setting the values of two var. say x and y

`abc obj1 = obj;`          // pointing to same memory so same values

But if there is a way where I can assign the values of one object to another, both having diff. memory. Simply said I want the values to copied not the address. Any operator or something can do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: Before you use `Clone`, read an explanation [why `Clone` is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2427946/335858).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `clone()` method (assuming the subclass implements the `java.lang.Cloneable` interface)

```
abc obj1 = obj.clone()
```

Bear in mind the default behavior of `clone()` is to return a shallow copy of the object. This means that the values of all of the original object’s fields are copied to the fields of the new object(it will not go through the entire graph of other objects).

I you want to "deep-copy" the object you can serialize and deserialize it.

*A deep copy makes a distinct copy of each of the object’s fields, recursing through the entire graph of other objects referenced by the object being copied*

more info at:

http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/

Comment: implementation of clone automatically assigns new memory space to this object, without the need of new keyword ?

Comment: Clone will create the new object in memory for you and will return a reference to it

Comment: That said, `clone` can have confusing and weird behavior, and it's frequently preferable to just implement a copy factory or constructor yourself.  (see e.g. Effective Java item 11)

Comment: Since there already was an answer to this effect, I have added the reference to Effective Java to it. Thanks, Louis.

Answer (score 2):

In case of using clone() method you have to implement Cloneable interface and write your own implementation for this method. I think that better to create a copy constructor in your class and use it.

For example:

```
public class YourClass() {
     private int prop1;
     private int prop2;
     ...
     // Getters and setters for properties.
     ...

     // Default constructor
     public YourClass() {
     }

     // Copy constructor
     public YourClass(YourClass instance) {
         this.prop1 = instance.getProp1();
         this.prop2 = instance.getProp2();
         // The same for other methods
     }

}
```

Here is [good post about clonning vs copy costructors vs factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use **deep cloning** .Implement [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) Interface in class `abc` and implement `clone()`

```
 abc obj = new abc(10,20); // setting the values of two var. say x and y

 abc obj1 = obj.clone();
```

`Cloning` depends on your class   structure .If you consider below simple class like your example.

```
 class ABC implements Cloneable {

private int a;
private int b;

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public ABC(int a, int b) {
    super();
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}

@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.clone();
}
}
```

Test it in main will return **false**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {

    ABC a = new ABC(1, 2);

    ABC b = (ABC) a.clone();

    System.out.println(a == b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to construct a new object.
As others point out, you can achieve this by implementing `Cloneable` and `clone()`, but you might as well might the new object explicit by implementing a Constructor or factory method that creates your new object out of the data held by the original.

The implementations won't differ much, yet I find the explicit instantiation less error prone to implement.

Josh Bloch comments on this in length in Effective Java. Depending on your edition, it is [item 10](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) or item 11 in Chapter 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'operator overloading'.
I know, I know, Java doesn't have it, but that doesn't stop you from 'using' it.

All you need to do is:

```
obj1.copy(obj2);
```

And inside the declaration of abc

```
public void copy(abc other) {
    var1 = other.var1;
    var2 = other.var2;
}
```

I wish to stress, that this is merely from memory and untested, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Alternative, you can use 'clone()', but be aware that 'references' within your class would get cloned over. Better to do it manually, really.

By overwriting 'copy', you can also make sure, that your subclasses are copied properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the clone method of Object class.

```
MyClass mobj = new MyClass("Vivek");

MyClass mobj1 = mobj.clone();
```

But for deep cloning try to use `Serialization and Deserialization`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use clone method.  The default behavior of clone is shallow copy.