# Different ways to copy an ArrayList

Tags: java

Is there any difference in between these three, assuming `a` has type `ArrayList<T>`?  (Aside from the fact that the compiler complains about unchecked operations in #3.)

1.

```
ArrayList<T> a1 = new ArrayList<T> (a);
```

2.

```
ArrayList<T> a2 = new ArrayList<T> ();
a2.addAll (a);
```

3.

```
ArrayList<T> a3 = (ArrayList<T>) (a.clone());
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet that #2 runs slower than #1 because of resizing issues, but I wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: You know Java is open source, right? And has documentation?

Comment: @DennisMeng Depends on if it allocates memory in a loop, or in one go.

Comment: @S.D. True. I'd imagine it does allocate memory all at once (and resize once) as opposed to in a loop (where it resizes probably `log n` times or whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning creates a new instance, holding the same elements. Clone works fine with Collections. So it is better not to use them.

```
ArrayList<T> a1 = new ArrayList<T> (a);
```

is a shallow copy and is comparatively faster.

This [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method) may help you further

Comment: Clone() works fine with Collections although it is considered broken. Correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: The javadoc for [ArrayList.clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()) says it makes a shallow copy; is the result any different from the constructor, #1?  (Not counting performance issues.)

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood. Then "So it is better not to use them." relates to "creates a new instance".

Comment: I fully agree with you!! :)