# Difference between copy and clone in context of java

Tags: java, collections, copy, clone

In a java interview, I was asked what is the different between copy and clone function. What I think both the method are used to make a copy of a object.

Another problem related with clone:

1. How to make a deep copy of a list and hashmap?
2. For above question, can we directly call list `Object#clone` method?

here copy refer to the function present in collections.

Comment: I haven't heard about a `copy` method in Java Collections framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java