# why clonning of Object's object is not possible?

Tags: java

Object class is having clone method for creating exactly duplicate objects. This method works for every class but why can't I create copy of object of Object class? Which Java concepts behind such behavior ?

I tried two different cases but it doesn't work. It gives compile time error : The method clone() from the type Object is not visible

```
Object o = new Object();
Object o2 = o.clone();

Object o = new Test(); // Some Test class
Object o2 = o.clone();
```

Comment: What is your use-case?

Comment: "it doesn't work" more detail please. What happend?

Comment: it gives compile time error : The method clone() from the type Object is not visible

Comment: [Java .clone() was a mistake and basically broken, don't use it, it leads to pain and suffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method/1106159#1106159)

Comment: Please note that this question is not a duplicate of the linked question, since the normal scope of protected methods does not apply to  .clone()

Answer (score 6):

`Object.clone()` has protected access (which is why you're getting your error), and thus cannot be called directly like this. You have to override `clone()` in your own class and make the class implement the [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface.

From the link below:

> The class Object does not itself implement the interface Cloneable, so
>   calling the clone method on an object whose class is Object will
>   result in throwing an exception at run time.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) for more details.

Comment: every class extends Object class, so protected clone method should be visible

Comment: Actually you can call .clone() on a non Object class without tht class implementing it, despite it being protected in java.lang.Object (doing so results in a runtime CloneNotSupportedException, unless you actually override .clone() and implement the Cloneable interface) .clone() in java is handled quite specially - the normal rules of visibility doesn't apply to sub classes. .clone() is also generally viewed as a misdesigned feature that shouldn't be used.