# Copy Constructor vs Cloneable. Why shouldn't I consider Cloneable?

Tags: java, object, copy-constructor, cloneable

I was reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106102/clone-vs-copy-constructor-vs-factory-method) and he mentioned a [link](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html), where author explains why shouldn't we use Cloneable. But, still have doubt what was stated there

> If I have an array of Cloneable, you would think that I could run down
>   that array and clone every element to make a deep copy of the array,
>   but I can't. **You can not cast something to Cloneable and call the clone
>   method, because Cloneable doesn't have a public clone method and
>   neither does Object**. If you try to cast to Cloneable and call the
>   clone method, the compiler will say you are trying to call the
>   protected clone method on object.

But, here I did

```
        Init s = Init.getInstance(); // getting instance
        int count=0;
        Cloneable[] v = new Cloneable[5]; // creating array
        Init x = s;
        Init y = new Init(s);
        try {
            while (count < 5) {
                v[count++] =  (Cloneable) s.clone(); // casting it.
            }

            s.setClassName("Example");
            System.out.println(((Init) v[2]).getClassName()); // Displaying.
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I was able to create Cloneable array and I did what author said will cause error Or Did I misunderstood author statement ? Anyone, please help me to understand the reason to choose Copy Constructor over Cloneable.

Comment: I am .net developer but oops concepts are similar in Java ans C# .As per my understanding In Copy Constructor the memory reference is same for both object the real or the copied.So when you change value of real object you will see it also effect the copied object. On clonable objects both have different memory reference they didn't depends they did not effect each other.

Answer (score 5):

You are not casting `s` to `Cloneable` and then calling `clone()` on it.

Instead you are calling `s.clone()` and then casting the result to `Clonable`.
You are able to do this because `s` is of type `Init` and `Init` has `public clone()` method.

Do this instead and you will find the compiler shouting,

```
 v[count++] =  ((Cloneable) s).clone();
```

Now let's say you want to clone an array (You obviously only know it's a `Cloneable` array. Which means you don't know it's actual Type.

```
Cloneable[] cloneArray = new Cloneable[5];
cloneArray[i] = new Init(); // Let's say it's initialized with different type objects but all `Cloneable`.

for (Cloneable object : cloneArray) {
      object.clone(); // Compiler wont allow it. And you don't know what type it is.
}
```

So, you basically cannot deep clone a Cloneable array.

Comment: That's fine. But, I was to copy it into Cloneable array . Right? Then, why shouldn't I choose Cloneable ?

Comment: No, it meant, you cannot Clone a Cloneable array. Check my edited answer.

Comment: So, this is the only things, which making difference between Copy Constructor and Cloneable ?